# Issue creating Laravel Nova tool

Tags: npm, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to create a Laravel Nova tool but when I do via the command line, after the first prompt (see below), I get this error

```
 Would you like to install the tool's NPM dependencies? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >

npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
```

I've run `npm i -g npm` but that doesn't seem to have fixed the problem. I can't seem to solve this, any ideas of how I can get this working?